# Nested forms with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form within my rails3.2 app for a Complaint, that also builds a new Company and Branch at the same time. That all works fine, but I want to store the id of the Company as the foreign key company_id in the Branch table.

This is my complaints controller:

```
def new
    @complaint = Complaint.new
    @complaint.build_company
    @complaint.build_branch(:company_id => '#Trying to set the company ID here')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @complaint }
    end
  end
```

What can I put after `:company_id =>` to assign the id of the object created above?

Comment: Do I need some kind of `after_create` action to do this?

Comment: Did you look at using accepts_nested_attributes_for and nested forms for this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be just like this?

```
@complaint.build_branch(:company_id => @complaint.company_id)
```

Comment: this won't work because `@complaint.company` is a new record which is also built on the same request.

Comment: You can't set the foreign key with build on an unsaved instance. It'll be overwritten on save.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to unsaved Company object & Complaint object. You have not outlined the details for the model, but I guess,

```
@complaint = Compplaint.create(#Whatever parameters are required)
company = @complaint.companies.create()  #Assuming has_many relationship
@complaint.branches.create(:comapny_id => company.id)
```

create saves the record and generates the id, where as build and new does not.

You should also explore, has_many :through in your model.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following code to the create action

```
def create
...
@complaint.branch.company = @complaint.company
@complaint.save
...
end
```